# PayTM payment gateway integration with Angular Universal

Tags: node.js, angular, express, payment-gateway, paytm

Im trying to integrate Paytm payment gateway into my angular universal project.

Issue is, When I try to run payment gateway Url, I see `Please wait! Do not refresh the page` and instead of taking me the payment portal it is redirecting to `callback` url immediately

I add the `/payment` routes in `server.ts`

Below is the code,

```
  server.get('/payment', (req, res) => {
    let params = {}
    params['MID'] = 'xxx',
      params['WEBSITE'] = 'WEBSTAGING',
      params['CHANNEL_ID'] = 'WEB',
      params['INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID'] = 'Retail',
      params['ORDER_ID'] = 'ORD0001',
      params['CUST_ID'] = 'CUST0011',
      params['TXN_AMOUNT'] = '100',
      params['CALLBACK_URL'] = 'http://localhost:' + port + '/callback',
      params['EMAIL'] = 'xxx@gmail.com',
      params['MOBILE_NO'] = 'xxxx'

    checksum_lib.genchecksum(params, 'xxx', function (err, checksum) {
      let txn_url = "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/order/process"

      let form_fields = ""
      for (let x in params) {
        form_fields += "<input type='hidden' name='" + x + "' value='" + params[x] + "'/>"

      }

      form_fields += "<input type='hidden' name='CHECKSUMHASH' value='" + checksum + "' />"

      var html = '<html><body><center><h1>Please wait! Do not refresh the page</h1></center><form method="post" action="' + txn_url + '" name="f1">' + form_fields + '</form><script type="text/javascript">document.f1.submit()</script></body></html>'
      res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
      res.write(html)
      res.end()
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing same order id in multiple requests. Orderid should be unique for every payment request.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the issue by referring to RESPCODE and RESPMSG coming in request body(since the callback is post request) of callback URL. Also, your order Id need to be different.